# WPF MVVM/Prism (6.2)/Unity - PopupWindowAction losing Owner across threads

Tags: wpf, mvvm, unity-container, prism, prism-6

I've been working almost exclusively in WPF/Prism using Unity and the MVVM pattern for about a year now.  I've had pretty good success in establishing a shell, several modules, and lots of cool stuff like scoped RegionManagers and shell-hosted common popups.

I came across something today that has me really scratching my head: `Cannot set Owner property to a Window that has been closed.`  I have a requirement to periodically check for updates to assemblies, prompt the user to restart the application, then handle that in the shell's ViewModel.  I'm doing that with a `bootstrapper.Run()`, and in the `bootstrapper` is a method that kills all windows.  Boom, `window that has been closed.`

The error makes sense (and is pretty obvious), but I can't seem to remedy the issue.  In `Prism 6.2`, this (and perhaps more/less) was introduced:

```
if (AssociatedObject != null)
            wrapperWindow.Owner = Window.GetWindow(AssociatedObject);
```

According to the stack trace, this is what is causing it to fail, because the `PopupWindowAction` thinks it's `Owner` is the now-closed `Window` (though it's worth noting this is new functionality and wasn't tested < 6.2).  I can't seem to find a way to re-instantiate it or `Set` the `Owner` (or something along those lines) -- or even what *should* happen here.

I'm firing this `PopupWindowAction` via an `InteractionRequestTrigger`, and all of that just opens a custom `UserControl`. Also, all of this happens on another thread, so I have to go back to the primary `Dispatcher` to find my scoped `InteractionService` (which basically fires an `INotification`):

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    var dialogResponse = InteractionService.ShowDialog(...
//...
```

**My question is**: can the popup not find it's parent because it's closed, or because it's now on a separate thread?  Beyond that, is this a reasonable thing to be talking about or is there a better solution to my users' requirements?

Answer (score 0):

This is definitively because the owner window is closed, has you said the dispatcher resolves the cross thread problem.

I don't know if I totally get it but…
If you are unloading all modules but keeping your shell open I would suggest you to add an InteractionRequestTrigger to your shellview  and create a composite command to raise it from your module